# Use js function in netsuite advanced pdf

Tags: netsuite

I wanted to print the item.rate value using substr function in javascript.

`var rate = ${item.rate}

var str = rate.substr(1,4);

<td>str</td>`

Need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code and try it.

${item.rate?substring(1, 4)}

You want more information about advance pdf html template 
https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html